# iPhone Human Interface Guidelines question

Tags: iphone, user-interface, opengl-es

iPhone Human Interface Guidelines -- Do they apply for OpenGL games?  GL games typically have custom buttons, custom lists, etc.  Take the Quake player list for example, if ported, it wouldnt be a typical UI list object.  Does this mean the reviewer in question would reject anything that wasn't using standard UI?  Or, is there an exception for games.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to refer to the section in the iPhone Human Interface Guidelines on "[Immersive Applications](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/DevelopingSoftware/DevelopingSoftware.html)".

Comment: Excellent link. I think a sentence in that section says a lot: "Users expect seeking and discovery to be part of the experience of an immersive application, so the use of nonstandard controls is often appropriate."

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. It's certainly true that you're not required to use the standard UIKit elements for games - buttons, labels, and so forth - but the core principles of the guidelines still hold. You should still be designing a UI that is responsive, consistent, and intuitive.

Keep in mind that these are *guidelines*. However strict they may be, if you have a good reason for disregarding them in creating your game, do so - just make sure that your UI is not obviously or fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 1):

The reviewers dont reject apps because they dont meet the guidelines… that is, they reject the apps because you are using something that contradicts a direct and purposeful guideline.

For instance, I have had many apps sent back because I used an icon of a man for showing your people.  It is intended to show your contacts.  Small things like this might get you into trouble, but if the context is clear and there is no confusion with elements that look like they came from cupertino, then you are ok.